# Dual Booting Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10 - Ubuntu does not see my SSD

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd

I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on my Yoga 900 laptop. I created an Ubuntu installation usb and can try Ubuntu just fine, but it does not appear to recognize my computer's SSD. The installer, gparted, disks, and fdisk -l all only list the usb as the only storage device. [Here is what these programs look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FheH4.jpg)

Also, if I try to hit change, +, or - on the installation windows the installer crashes. Does anyone know how I can get Ubuntu to recognize my SSD so that I can use it during the installation process? [For reference, this is what my hard drive looks like in windows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK8GG.png)

Edit: So after an uproar on Reddit, [it turns out Lenovo has specifically confirmed that the 900 cannot run Linux.](https://www.engadget.com/2016/09/21/lenovo-pc-linux-trouble/) This is extremely disappointing for a laptop that costs so much.

Comment: Is Windows hibernated, or its fast start up is on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Windows is shut down and fast start up is off

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem (on a Dell XPS 13). The issue for me was that the SATA bios setting was set to raid (which Ubuntu doesn't seem to recognize?).

The following link (second post/ first answer) explains how to change it to ahci:

http://www.eightforums.com/drivers-hardware/53429-migrating-raid-ssd-switching-ahci.html

(edit: You can ignore the unplugging of the disk in the fifth step and the seventh step completly, those are not needed to changing to ahci)

Just keep in mind to make some backups if you care about the data on your machine. Before finding the link above I did mess around a bit myself and got a few problems rebooting.

Besides that, this worked on my machine so no idea how it will fare on yours. You probably want to be extra careful if you actually have multiple disks or raid setup or something like that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason (manufacturer I guess) there is no ahci option in the bios. Also, I don't think I'd be able to physically unplug the drive. My older 1st gen Yoga has the ahci option in bios but not this computer. I got it working for now by installing to a low profile usb 3.0 drive and it seems to be working ok. It's not as good as if it were installed on my SSD but it works for what I need

Comment: Aah sorry to hear it did not work for you, but good that you found another option. 
I think the unplugging of the drive is more related to the specific problem of in that post, and not needed for the change in sata mode, will edit my answer to mention that.