# Can't install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10: can't choose installation type

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, disk

This question is duplicate of [Unable to install Ubuntu 18.04 to dual boot with windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117471/unable-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-to-dual-boot-with-windows-10/1177361#1177361).

There is difference with: [Ubuntu 14.04.2 installer does not recognize partitions when trying to install dual-boot alongside Windows 8.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609107/ubuntu-14-04-2-installer-does-not-recognize-partitions-when-trying-to-install-du?rq=1).
I doesn't see any disk expect USB on `gdisk` command. It is more like [Dual Booting Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10 - Ubuntu does not see my SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767511/dual-booting-ubuntu-16-04-with-windows-10-ubuntu-does-not-see-my-ssd?rq=1).

"I try to run the installer I get stuck at selecting a partition." The error's description the same as in the question.

After 1th page of "Preparing to install Ubuntu" (where I can install 3rd party programm) I can't choose how to install Ubuntu (alongside with Windows or erase disc, for example).

Image: https://ibb.co/6JfB2YQ
or https://drive.google.com/file/d/10KLTdC26tnGB0WPR9G8_fQGqAGRRMC-u/view?usp=sharing

There is what I see on `gdisk` command:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10V3WaUXcW-wq3gM5zVU9HHBWUhZ72-8b/view?usp=sharing

`sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda` returns `no block devices found`.

If I choose `Install now`, I got error message:

```
No root file system is defined
Please correct this from the partition menu
```

But I can't choose one.

- The same problem, but with USB 2.0.
- PC brand/model: Dell Vosto 5480 (with SSD)
- BIOS: 2.2.0
- Has System Firmware 2.1.0 (actual).
- Intel Chipset SATA\PCI and Disc space controller drivers are actual.
- I have disk C for Windows (NTFS) and disk 0 part 4 for Linux (file system: RAW or unallocated, I tryed borh types).

Sorry for my English.

Comment: @karel more like: https://askubuntu.com/questions/767511/dual-booting-ubuntu-16-04-with-windows-10-ubuntu-does-not-see-my-ssd?rq=1 (see images)

Comment: @karel thanks, it may be "A damaged partition table" from answer. But i don't solve problem yet.